# Cocoapods on Windows invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 error

Tags: windows, cocoa, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm currently trying to run cocoapods on Windows, but after installing it I try to run `pod --version` and get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/pod:23:in '<main>'
    3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/pod:23:in 'load'
    2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.0/bin/pod:55:in '<top (required)>'
    1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in 'run'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:168:in 'verify_xcode_license_approved!': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

I can't figure out what might be causing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure Cocoapods is supported on Windows? I can't imagine a dependency manager for iOS and Mac projects having Windows support.

Comment: [CocoaPods added Windows support on 1.7.0](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.7.0-beta/#windows-support), as far as I know it only covers a few basic operations, but it should be able to do what I need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question, the problem seems to be related to the terminal encoding. Windows terminal does not use UTF-8 by default, so you have to change it's encoding, you can set it to UTF-8 by running:

`chcp 65001`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this command wasn't work in powershell, but in cmd.exe work fine! maybe this can help